# Android: How to load the main activity while on the splash screen

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments, android-activity, android-asynctask

I got a splash screen activity and a main activity with webview. It takes 4 to 5 seconds after loading of the main activity which is after the Splash screen, I wanted solution for start loading the main activity parallelly while in the splash screen

Thank you in advance

Comment: well, what have you tried?

Comment: @ZUNJAE  A webview app, but I wanted it to load sooner after the Splash screen, but takes 4-5 sec which would minimise if I run splash screen activity and main activity parallelly.please help with this

Comment: You need to ask a specific question. Then you will receive specific answers.

Answer (score 1):

Within splash activity you should create background service to finish time consuming jobs,
then transfer obtained data to main activity using bundle.Thus your main activity will load faster.

There are many ways to complete background tasks,please ref this [doc](https://developer.android.com/training/best-background).

Answer (score 0):

Have loader on your MainActivity, once everything is loaded, just set loader's visibility to `GONE`.
No need to use SplashScreen in this case

Comment: No, splash screen is important

Comment: @Kàrthîkßàlàkrìshña what's in your splashScreenActivity? Some animation? If so you can add your animation in progressLoader, and make it work